# SSRS Performance Mystery

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure that returns about 50000 records in 10sec using at most 2 cores in SSMS.  The SSRS report using the stored procedure was taking 20min and would max out the processor on an 8 core server for the entire time.  The report was relatively simple (i.e. no graphs, calculations).  The report did not appear to be the issue as I wrote the 50K rows to a temp table and the report could display the data in a few seconds.  I tried many different ideas for testing altering the stored procedure each time, but keeping the original code in a separate window to revert back to.  After one Alter of the stored procedure, going back to the original code, the report and server utilization started running fast, comparable to the performance of the stored procedure alone.  Everything is fine for now, but I am would like to get to the bottom of what caused this in case it happens again.  Any ideas?

Comment: Indexes on tables? A stale execution plan? Statistics got updated? Did you have a SqlProfiler log? That will help in the future..

Comment: Just rendering or rendering as PDF?

Comment: Dan - Just rendering a standard report to the web.  Rene - I did not run SqlProfiler during the troubleshooting.  I have run it on local queries, but is there anything special I need to do to log the SSRS DB calls?  I also did not dig into the SSRS Execution logs, but was considering it if the other troubleshooting had not worked.  How can you detect a stale execution plan?

Comment: Is your SSRS server the same machine as your database server? I ask because I have found that SSRS frequently performs badly with large datasets *even when* the report server is on a different machine to the database - this helps narrow the problem down to SSRS, rather than the relevant query. It seems as though Microsoft prefer SSIS to be used for large data extracts, rather than SSRS.

Comment: Did your report have any drill-down links in it? We've seen these result in large temporary data being stuffed inside of the Report Server's database.

Comment: Mark - The SSRS server is on the same machine as the db server.  I plan to separate them when I move to 2012 and have the needed hardware, but that's still several months out.  I definitely agree that it will help to isolate the problem.

Comment: Similar to @Mario, any subreports?  Subreports are executed once per parent-row, so the overhead of loading & executing them can drive the processing time WAY up.

Comment: Might be a bad cached query plan. [`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) cleans all old plans and generates new plans on the next use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with a SQL Profiler trace of both the stored procedure when you execute it normally, and then the same SP when it's called by SSRS. Make sure you include the execution plans involved, so you can see if it's making some bad decisions (though that seems unlikely - the SQL Server should execute an optimal - or at least consistent - plan regardless of the query's source).

We used to have cases where Business Objects would execute stored procs dozens of times for no aparent reason and it lead to occasionally horrible performance, though I've never seen that same behavior with SSRS. It may be somewhere to start, though. You'll also see the execution begin/end times - that will make it clear if it's the database layer that's hanging up, or if the SQL Server hands back the data in 10 seconds and then it's the SSRS service that's choking somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The primary solution to speeding SSRS reports is to **cache** the reports. If one does this (either my preloading the cache at 7:30 am for instance) or caches the reports on-hit, one will **find massive gains in load speed.**

You may also find that monthly restarts of SSRS application domain to resolve your issue.

Please note that **I do this daily and professionally** and am not simply waxing poetic on SSRS

Caching in SSRS
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx

Pre-loading the Cache
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155876.aspx

If you do not like initial reports taking long and your data is static i.e. a daily general ledger or the like, meaning the data is relatively static over the day, **you may increase the cache life-span**.

**Finally**, you may also opt for business managers to instead receive these reports via **email subscriptions**, which will send them a point in time Excel report which they may find easier and more systematic.

You can also use parameters in SSRS to allow for easy parsing by the user and faster queries. In the query builder type IN(@SSN) under the Filter column that you wish to parameterize, you will then find it created in the parameter folder just above data sources in the upper left of your BIDS GUI.
[If you do not see the data source section in SSRS, hit CTRL+ALT+D.

See a nearly identical question here: [Performance Issuses with SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976133/performance-issuses-with-ssrs/11229634#11229634)